# Cannot hide context menu made by jeegoocontext

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

Here is the link to an example of my website i am working on:
https://grenada.lumc.nl/LOVD3/shared/genes

I am trying to hide a context menu that has been generated by jeegoocontext(The menu that pops up when hovering over the tabs at the top of the page, e.g. "Screenings"). When i hover over the tab, the context window appears as it should. However, when i mouseout of the tab without actually having touched the context menu(e.g. exit the top from the top) then the context menu does not hide and i can't get it to do so.

If i have mouse overed the menu before exiting, then it behaves as it should. Does anyone have a solution for this that does not involve using a different library than jeegoocontext?

**EDIT :**
This is the link to the jeegoocontext zip with the original .js file in the folder jeegoocontext.
http://www.planitworks.nl/uploads/afbeelding/components/downloads/jeegoocontext_1_3.zip

Cheers,

lugte098

Comment: Please post the code which is making the sub-menus appear. As far as I can see in the source of the page, it's currently minified so we cannot help.

Comment: Do i need to provide more information maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try put your script in footer of your page like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var aMenuOptions = {
        widthOverflowOffset: 0,
        heightOverflowOffset: 1,
        startLeftOffset: -20,
        event: "mouseover",
        openBelowContext: true,
        autoHide: true,
        delay: 100,
        onSelect: function(e, context){
            if($(this).hasClass("disabled"))
            {              
                return false;
            } else {
                window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
                return false;
            }
        },
    };
    $('#tab_genes').jeegoocontext('menu_tab_genes', aMenuOptions);
    $('#tab_transcripts').jeegoocontext('menu_tab_transcripts', aMenuOptions);
    $('#tab_variants').jeegoocontext('menu_tab_variants', aMenuOptions);
    $('#tab_individuals').jeegoocontext('menu_tab_individuals', aMenuOptions);
    $('#tab_diseases').jeegoocontext('menu_tab_diseases', aMenuOptions);
    $('#tab_screenings').jeegoocontext('menu_tab_screenings', aMenuOptions);
    $('#tab_submit').jeegoocontext('menu_tab_submit', aMenuOptions);
});
```

The problem is that the script might be running before hmtl DOM be complete.
Try this.